# Select All Checkbox for enable boxex in Gridview

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a select all script for a Grid which selects all the enabled and disabled boxes, I want the script to select only the enabled checkboxes on the grid and discard the disabled checkboxes.

tried different methods but none of them are working.
here is my Java Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function CheckAllPaid(Checkbox) {
     var GridVwHeaderChckbox = document.getElementById("<%=dg.ClientID%>");
    for (i = 1; i < GridVwHeaderChckbox.rows.length; i++) {
            GridVwHeaderChckbox.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked = Checkbox.checked ;
        }
    }

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use selectors. This will give you all checked inputs inside that grid panel.

EDIT:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function CheckAllPaid(Checkbox) {
var GridVwHeaderChckbox = document.getElementById("<%=dg.ClientID%>");
var checked = GridVwHeaderChckbox.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').filter(function(input){
     if(!input.disabled){
         input.checked = true; 
         return true;
     }else{
         return false;
     }
});


</script>
```

Comment: can you write the full script ?

Comment: this still selects disabled checkboxes, the request was to select only the enables checkboxes inside the grid.

Comment: I dont understand your purpose. Do you want to `check` all the checkboxes with the code ? Or you want to fetch what is checked at that time ?

Comment: My grid includes checkboxes which some are enabled for selecting and some are disabled and users cannot select or check them, the select all script which I am looking for is required to select only the checkboxes which are enabled. on the code which I mentioned on the top, the script is selecting all the checkboxes regardless of the "Enabled = true or false" status.

Comment: I added a snapshot for the issue

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will work. It loops all checkboxes in the GridView and checks/unchecks them based on `is_checked` or evaluate their status etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeAllCheckBoxes(is_checked) {
        $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
            $(this).find("td input:checkbox").each(function (index, element) {
                this.checked = is_checked;
                //or
                if (this.checked) {
                    //do stuff
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Or if you want a all checkboxes in a specific column checked/unchecked, send along the column index.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeAllCheckBoxes(is_checked, columnIndex) {
        $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
            $(this).find("td input:checkbox").each(function (index, element) {
                if (index == columnIndex) {
                    this.checked = is_checked;
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input disabled="disabled" class="YourCheckBoxClacc" type="checkbox" value="10" />  
<input class="YourCheckBoxClacc" type="checkbox" value="30" />
```

> JQuery :

```
$('.YourCheckBoxClacc:enabled:checked')
```

This will set `Checked` only to the **enabled** checkboxes.